# Laravel backpack csrf problem while deleting entries

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have installed laravel backpack, followed the official tutorial: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-tutorial and created Tag model with admin crud.
Everything but delete works fine. While clicking the delete button in admin panel I am getting an error `There's been an error. Your item might not have been deleted.`

In devtools I saw that I am getting a 419 error and the message says `CSRF token mismatch.`. What may cause the problem and how can I fix it?

Information in devtools Console:

[image]

Information in devtools Network:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this I have copied ***delete.blade.php*** file from
vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/buttons/delete.blade.php

to

resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/buttons/delete.blade.php

Then I added x-csrf-token header to ajax request in 29th line of file

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},
```

Now the request is sent with x-csrf-token header and delete is successful

Comment: Thanks for following up with the solution! I wonder why this has happened for you... I can't replicate it in any of my installs... Do you have any custom JS in your admin pages that messes with the CSRF token?